# Debugging EXE File in Windbg and How to set Breakpoints in Assembly

Tags: gdb, windbg, shellcode, nasm, assembly

I am trying to set a breakpoint (created in assembly) and step into an EXE file line by line to watch registers and memory behavior. I have done this easily with gdb under Linux like this.

```
gdb -q ./AssembledLinkedFile -tui
break _start  (or break *&code for C using shellcode)
run
stepi
```

This works perfectly. However, The documentation for Windbg does not seem so straight forward.

Since using GoLink adds several lines of asm, I need to find my assembly and start at the beginning  (_start:)

Current process.

1. Write my assembly program.
2. Assemble (on linux) -  nasm -f win64 messageBox64bit.nasm -o messageBox64bit.obj
3. Link with golink (Windows) - golink \console messageBox64bit.obj
4. messageBox64bit.EXE created and works fine. Executed on Windows

After I open the messageBox64bit.EXE in Windbg, how can I  set a breakpoint in my assembly (_start:), then step into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems  `bp $exentry` should set breakpoint on the entrypoint, then you can continue (`g`) until you hit it.